# Inserting into an associative table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Say I have table1 and table2, each has a form with dynamic input fields to insert data to these tables. Normally I would just directly get the last insert ID to insert it into a foreign key of a single table but now I'm dealing two tables, plus with dynamic input fields, and don't know how to insert them in an associative table of many-to-many relationship. I was thinking of storing the last insert ids in an array but my thoughts stopped there and I'm not even sure about it.

```
table1
------
t1_id (pk)
desc

assoctable
------
status
t1_id (fk)
t2_id (fk)


table2
------
t2_id (pk)
attrb
```

Update: I didn't include my codes but here is it. They do work without problems so far and can insert the user inputs to the database.

**View**:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc[]" id="row1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="attrib[]" id="row2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addRow1()">Add Row</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addRow2()">Add Row</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
$descs = $this->input->post('desc');
$attrbs = $this->input->post('attrb');

foreach($descs as $key => $val){
    $fields = array(
        'desc' => $val
    );
    $table1_result = $this->model_test->insert_table1($fields);
}
foreach($attrbs as $key => $val){
    $fields = array(
        'attrb' => $val
    );
    $table2_result = $this->model_test->insert_table2($fields);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function insert_table1($data) {
    $this->db->insert('table1', $data);
}
function insert_table2($data) {
    $this->db->insert('table2', $data);
}
```

Comment: There is not enough info of how your UI looks, but generally this can be done:

If you use regular form-submit, then Name attributes of the input fields should carry some index(counter) that is relating them, as: <input name="table1[counter][desc]" and related <input name="table2[counter][attrb]" ; When dynamically generating form-filds, counter is incremented.

If you are using AJX calls to save the data(recommended because the beckend is then simpler) then use Custom Attributes in the input fields, as:<input table='table1' count='{some JS Object.counter}'

Comment: I've heard of associative arrays, what is an associative table?

Comment: An associative entity. I think I should have used that term instead, no? >.<

Comment: I think you are referring to `assoctable` table, which is known as a junction table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to it. Thanks for the information and link, I didn't know about the term Junction Table. I looked at the usage example and still couldn't figure out what to do. Would you be so kind as to shed me some light on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an ORM of some kind, where each object represents an entity within a particular table. To do what you are trying to do you need to implement a transaction, which ensures data consistency by committing either all or none of the queries. Here is some generic code to get you on the right track:

```
// HUGE CAVEAT! This assumes that $desc and $attr arrays are aligned

try {

    $this->db->startTransaction();

    foreach ($descriptions as $key => $description) {

        $table1 = new Table1;
        $table2 = new Table2;
        $linkingTable = new LinkingTable;

        $table1->setDescription($description);

        $table1->save();

        $table2->setAttribute($attributes[$key]);

        $table2->save();

        // Here is where the magic happens, notice that are making a call to getId on both objects, so even though the transaction hasn't committed yet, the database has allocated us the ids
        $linkingTable->setTable1Id($table1->getId());
        $linkingTable->setTable2Id($table2->getId());

        $linkingTable->save();
    }

    $this->db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    error_log(sprintf('Exception: %s', $e->getMessage()));

    $this->db->rollback();
}
```

-- Reference to Comment --

No idea how your form is setup, but typically a form should represent a primary object, with the ability to link other objects to it via the junction (or linking table as I like to call them).

Take for example a bookstore example. You create a form where you can save a book to the store, and as part of the form you have multiple authors who may have co-authored the book. When you save the form, the book is only one object, so you don't need to worry about the arrays aligning b/c you will only have one array, the authors.

If you cannot setup your form following the book/authors example, then in theory, you could align your keys by associating each form element like `descs[1]` and ensure that `assocs[1]` aligns, so when you submit the form, the previous example I gave should work.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about transactions. Uhm one more question, what if the arrays are not aligned? It's been bugging me. Couldn't seem to formulate the logic for it.

Comment: Populate the arrays so that they are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Thanks to Mr. Mike for enlightening me. After every insert I stored the last id's of both separately.

```
$table1_id = array();

foreach($descs as $key => $val){
   $fields = array(
       'desc' => $val
);
   $table1_result = $this->model_test->insert_table1($fields);
   $table1_id[] = $this->model_test->getlastid();
}
```

The table2 has the same similar codes. Then this is how I insert them to the junction table.

```
foreach($table1_id as $key => $val) {
    foreach($table2_id as $key2 => $val2) {
        $field = array(
            'status' => '0',
            't1_id' => $val2,
            't2_id' => $val
        );
        $result = $this->model_admin->insert_assoctable($field);
    }
}
```